# install an apk file programmatically after downloading(android studio)

Tags: java, android

i know this question has already been asked, but none of them solves my problem. I want to install an apk (non market app) file which i have downloaded.

heres my code:

```
                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.temp.tempaa/files/Download/update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(install);
```

but when executing this code the package installer is not launching. Instead i am getting an open with popup.[Here's The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Snr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Error is you made the Intent of "install" and using setDataAndType on "intent".

Correct code will be:-

```
Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.temp.tempaa/files/Download/update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(install);
```